# Div container causes overflow

Tags: css, html

I tried to refurbish my whole site but cannot manage to fix an overflow inside a container. I tried to make the site structure as simple as possible, but I can't find the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/x12bkd9g/

```
<body class="page-header-fixed">
    <div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="page-sidebar">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="top-bar"></div>
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="content-container-left col-md-8 class-with-no-padding">
                            <div class="toolbar">
                                <div class="portlet-body">
                                    <div class="form-group form-group-default top-bar">
                                        {!! Form::label('location', 'Position') !!}
                                        {!! Form::text('location', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="map-container">
                                <div id="gis-map-view"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-container-right col-md-4 class-with-no-padding">
                            Test
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tailScripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

The CSS:

```
* HEADER */
.class-with-no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.page-header.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.page-header-fixed .page-container {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.page-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-sidebar-wrapper {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
}

.page-sidebar {
  background-color: #008000;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


.page-content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.page-content-wrapper .page-content {
}

.page-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content,
.main-content > .row,
.main-content > .row > div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content-container-left {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content-container-right {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.top-bar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.map-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#gis-map-view {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Why is my inner container containing a map overflowing. I am not sure, where the problem is:

[image]

**Update**
I added the following to the code:

```
.map-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

But now the map is gone:
[image]

**Update 2**
After changing to

```
* {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.map-container {
  float: none !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This happened:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page? Without it, there is not much I can see that would outline your CSS error. There are many CSS classes you are using which are not shown in your snippet. These classes are similar to Drupal, which I'm now assuming that your using, but without being able to interrogate the page and see exactly what styles are being applied.

Comment: Can you add this code on jsfiddle ?

Comment: I will add the code to JSFiddle. One moment please

Comment: In such situations I create a small example in jsfiddle that only contains the problem..

Comment: My assumption is that, because your `map-container` has a relative size limit of percentage based. That normally would work, if the parent container has a defined size, percentage of the page or absolute. Your problem may be that the `map-conatiner` is the child of an element with a Bootstrap class applied to it. Bootstrap classes apply a float property of `float: left`, removing the element from the DOM and re-including it later. This will de-reference your parent container from the body size of your page.

Comment: I doubt it will work the same in JSFiddle, unless you include all of the CSS stylesheets that are being applied to your webpage.

Comment: hm... I am not sure if I can fully recreate the issue in jsfiddle. I will try.

Comment: The more I look at this, I think it may work if you add these few styles to your definition of your `map-container` class: `float: left; position: relative; min-height: 1px;`

Comment: well.. I did what you suggested. I added a new image to the question as an update. now the map is completley gone

Comment: When I remove the `float: left` the map reappears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76368/discussion-between-sesc360-and-webwanderer).

Comment: Ah, of course. Disregard that statement. I'm writing up an answer.

Comment: I just added a JS Fiddle. The problem is, the map is not working

Comment: Ok, this is going to be terrible, but just humor me for a second. Add this to your CSS file: `* { float:left; position:relative; min-height: 1px;}  .map-container { float: none !important;}` and tell me what happens. Just an experiment.

Comment: ok...just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here which will affect the overflow property of your `map-container` div. The most obvious and most important thing to do is make sure that your `map-container`'s dimension properties reference either a parent property or a defined property.

Your `map-container`'s height is defined as:

```
height: 100%;
```

..yet when moving up the parent hierarchy, whose CSS classes follow:

```
> "content-container-left col-md-8 class-with-no-padding"

> "row"

> "main-content"

> "page-content"

> "page-content-wrapper"

> "page-container"

> "page-header-fixed"
```

..we can see that the only classes offering any possibly referential height property are: `row`, `page-content`, and `page-content-wrapper`. All of which have a property of :`height: 100%;`

This will not work because there are multiple breaks in the chain of inheritance. Unfortunately, a div with a property of: `height: 100%;` within a div with a property of: `height: auto;` (which is default) will not behave as you think. Each element along the inheritance chain must have a declare height property for this to work. It should work if you add:

```
.page-header-fixed {
    height: 100%; /*or any pixel dimension*/
}

.page-container {
    height: 100%; /*or any pixel dimension*/
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%; /*or any pixel dimension*/
}

.content-container-left {
    height: 100%; /*or any pixel dimension*/
}
```

The other issue now stems from the fact that you are using a Bootstrap column class within the inheritance chain of your `map-container`. All Bootstrap column classes apply the properties of: `float: left; position: relative; min-height: 1px;`. The issue is the `float: left;` property. Floating an element removes the element from the DOM and adds the element after each "non-floated" element has been "loaded." This breaks the chain of inheritance. Either each parent needs to be floated (which we saw caused your map to disappear for some reason) or you need to remove the Bootstrap column class (which I suggest you do). **Remove the class `col-md-8` from your `map-container`'s parent container and add:**

```
.content-container-left {
    width: 66.6666667%;
}
```

Comment: Hi WebWanderer! I will try this approach! But one question to that: I thought using `class="row"` is the way to go if I build up grids. Shouldn't it be used like that? Or other way around: when is the best option to use row. Is the layout I have not a typical use case?

Comment: The `row` class is meant to be used when using the column classes, yet I tend to believe that it should only be used either directly within the `<body>` element or within an element which has a `col-` class applied to it (that is if you are using `col-` class elements within your `row` element). This is all due to the `float: left;` property of the `col-` classes, which can cause A LOT of havoc if used incorrectly, and I honestly have no idea why Bootstrap used floats. Maybe to make your page break if you don't use `col-` classes everywhere? I don't know, but read up on floats. They suck.

Comment: The `row` class can be used anywhere, but if your using `col-` classes as well, you should try and pay attention to all of your floats, for they may be causing odd functionality if used improperly, especially for elements which you expect to have `auto` dimensions. If you use a float, use it in a float.

Comment: But aren't most of all the dashboards around, as far as I have seen them, built up with `row` and `col-` classes? Nested inside a lot of divs? I just saw an example but the `float` hasn't been set there. I have difficulties to imagine the right way to use this class right now

Comment: Yes, yet these classes need to be used nearly **everywhere** to have the proper functionality, or at least everywhere up the parent tree from any element using them. The moral of the story is that you need to be careful when using floats because they can cause a lot of issues they didn't expect, which I am absolutely certain is the issue with your map. You lost scope of referential dimension on your element due to the float property of the Bootstrap column class you used, that's all. The easiest way to fix it is to remove the Bootstrap class, or, to re-factor your entire layout. You choose.

Comment: I refactored the layout to your suggestion and it works smoothly! Thank you very very much WebWanderer! This was a very thoughtful answer and a lot of effort and patience in explaining! I am very greateful for that and learnt quite a bit!!

Comment: That's awesome! I'm very glad it worked. I do like using Bootstrap classes myself, but just be careful when using them, as I've stated plenty of times earlier. It could cost you everything. Have fun!